# Generate assert statements on all public properties of an object

Tags: .net, resharper, mstest, t4

In my current project we want to test our mapping from sql to datamodels through a set of integration tests.

For this we need to basically assert all public properties on an object.
Is there a way to automatically generate assert statements for all public properties on an object? Setting the expected values would be our job, but the laborious job of writing the numerous assert statements would be something a computer could do.

I'm thinking of using a T4 template or maybe harness the awesomeness of resharper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could use is the test generation of Visual Studio:

```
1. Open the class file;
2. Right-click within it;
3. Click on the Create Unit Tests ... option
4. Setup where you want to generate your tests from the dialog
```

Comment: This seems to indeed go towards what I'm looking for. The generated code however is quite noisy. It would be awesome if the template for it would be adaptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can harness the awesomeness of ReSharper by creating a plug-in that does what you need. [This guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6+Plugin+Development) will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

T4 sounds like a simple low-effort option, too. Also fun to do, and not very documentation-heavy (unlike e.g. making a Resharper plugin). Be sure to put the T4 template in a different assembly, so that you can use the `@assembly` directive to refer to the assembly that you're generating tests for. Then, use reflection right from inside the T4 template to loop through the class's properties. Or something like that.

Make sure you refer to the assembly with a full path (or put it in the GAC).

I'd recommend the [tangible T4 editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/60297607-5fd4-4da4-97e1-3715e90c1a23/) (no need for the bundled "modeling tools") for some decent syntax highlighting and intellisense.